# Select weighted random rows based on value of table

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have this table that consist this 2 columns:

[sample_data_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke7ND.png)

Is there a way to select random results from it with weighted country (maybe this weight data is store from another table?) ? like for example:

[sample_data_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eMom.png)

So if I do a select of 2 rows, it will tend to pick result with more weights (US, DE) instead of (KR or VN)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you put more details about your table? And a simple reproducible example. This will help us to answer faster your question.

Comment: Updated with image ! @WilliamPrigolLopes

Answer (score 0):

If you have counts in the second table and you want random results from the first, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by country order by random()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t join
     limits l
     on t.seqnum <= l.limit
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question, I need it to be weighted random, not just random (the number on 2nd table is not count, it's probability that it will be pick - you can think of it as percent)

Comment: @NguyenKen . . . You misunderstand the answer.  This returns exactly the distributions in the second table.  Well, weights and counts are essentially the same thing.  You might need to multiply them by some number to get a bigger sample.